# TextView in listViews added inside a Fragment displaying but empty (no text)

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, textview

I want to display a list of items containing 2 textview in one of my fragment. Something really simple since I'm learning how to use listviews.

Here is my code:

```
public class CommandeFragment extends Fragment{
private BarMenu myMenu;

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.commande_layout,container, false);

    myMenu = (BarMenu) getArguments().getSerializable(MENU_KEY);

    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < myMenu.drinks.size(); i++){
        HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("Name",myMenu.drinks.get(i).drinkName);
        hm.put("Price",myMenu.drinks.get(i).drinkPrice.toString());
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"drinkName","drinkPrice"};

    int[] to = {R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(myView.getContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_commande_layout, from, to);

    ListView listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return myView;
}

}
```

When I run this, I got a list of textviews placed correctly but the problem is that the text inside is empty. I've try multiple advice about the xml files online but I'm pretty sure it's fine.

Here it is in case:

listview_commande_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

commande_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bar Menu Layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use `ArrayAdapter`/`BaseAdapter` if you want to display multiple item in you listview. And use `ListFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names you pass to your adapter don't match the column names in your  HashMap ("Name" vs. "drinkName"). If you update these to match, it should work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myMenu.drinks.size(); i++){
    HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("Name",myMenu.drinks.get(i).drinkName);
    hm.put("Price",myMenu.drinks.get(i).drinkPrice.toString());
    aList.add(hm);
}

String[] from = {"Name","Price"}; //changed from {"drinkName","drinkPrice"}
```